# UNIX_TIMESTAMP of 1970-01-01 00:00:01 is 0 in mysql

Tags: mysql, epoch

I tried the following query:

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:01');

I expected it will give "1" but it gave "0".

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:01')
0
```

I am getting `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 01:00:01');` as "1".

More Details:

```
@@global.time_zone  @@session.time_zone     @@system_time_zone
SYSTEM              SYSTEM                  GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because of Daylight saving.

As we're currently one hour forward, the GMT is +1. So `01:00:01` matches `00:00:01` + 1 hour.

See also : http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/